# OSGi with JPA: Service not starting although code seems ok

Tags: java, jpa, osgi

Yea I know I should be using `Declarative Services` or `Blueprint` however I am trying to figure out one simple example using the lower level APIs to get the feel of OSGi.

I just want to know **what is wrong with the code and why I can't get the service started at all!!??**

I have used *two approaches* here: one with `ServiceTracker` and another with `ServiceReference`, I know both are *unreliable* but could someone plz help me out to get this sample code working. Would be so much grateful for this!!

Here is my code:

I have a simple **Accounts** Entity class:

```
package model.account;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Account {

@Id @GeneratedValue
int id;
double balance;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account{" + "id=" + id + ", balance=" + balance + '}';
}

}
```

The **AccountClient** as:

```
package client;

public class AccountClient {

public void run(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Account a = new Account();
    a.setBalance(100.0);
    em.persist(a);

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    TypedQuery<Account> q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Account a", Account.class);
    List<Account> results = q.getResultList();
    System.out.println("\n*** Account Report ***");
    for (Account acct : results) {
        System.out.println("Account: " + acct);
    }
    em.close();
}
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="Accounts" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>model.account.Account</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/accountDB;create=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>

        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1"/>                        
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>

    </properties>
```

And finally the **Activator** with `ServiceReference` as:

```
package client;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

BundleContext ctx;
ServiceReference[] serviceReferences;
EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    ctx = context;
    System.out.println("Gemini JPA Basic Sample started");

    try{
        serviceReferences = context.getServiceReferences(
                      EntityManagerFactory.class.getName(),
                      "(osgi.unit.name=Accounts)");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(serviceReferences != null){
        emf = (EntityManagerFactory)context.getService(serviceReferences[0]);
    }
    if(emf != null){
        new AccountClient().run(emf);
    }
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    if(serviceReferences != null){
        context.ungetService(serviceReferences[0]);
    }
    System.out.println("Gemini JPA Basic Sample stopped");
}
}
```

**`ServiceTracker`**:

```
package client;
public class Activator implements BundleActivator, ServiceTrackerCustomizer {

BundleContext ctx;
ServiceTracker emfTracker;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    ctx = context;
    System.out.println("Gemini JPA Basic Sample started");

    /* We are in the same bundle as the persistence unit so the services should be 
     * available when we start up (if nothing bad happened) and the tracker is really 
     * just saving us the lookup, but this is the idea of how you would listen for a 
     * persistence unit coming from another bundle.
     */
    emfTracker = new ServiceTracker(ctx, EntityManagerFactory.class.getName(), this);
    emfTracker.open();
    System.out.println("Started finally!!");
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    emfTracker.close();
    System.out.println("Gemini JPA Basic Sample stopped");
}

/*========================*/
/* ServiceTracker methods */
/*========================*/

public Object addingService(ServiceReference ref) {
    System.out.println("reached in add");
    Bundle b = ref.getBundle();
    System.out.println("Got ref");
    Object service = b.getBundleContext().getService(ref);
    System.out.println("service");
    String unitName = (String)ref.getProperty(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.JPA_UNIT_NAME);
    System.out.println("search");

    if (unitName.equals("Accounts")) {
        new AccountClient().run((EntityManagerFactory)service);
        System.out.println("Found and started");
    }
    return service;
}
public void modifiedService(ServiceReference ref, Object service) {}
public void removedService(ServiceReference ref, Object service) {}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your manifest contain the Meta-Persistence header and all the dependencies as described in the [JPA Documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation/CreatingAnApplication)?
Are all bundles startet up?

Maybe this helps [Installing and Starting Gemini JPA Applications](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation/OtherTopics#Installing_and_Starting_Applications)

Comment: Yes, I have done the same way. I tried another approach where it will instantiate the object of EntityManagerFactory and calls Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Accounts"); where it gives the error for "No persistence unit found named Accounts". Do you have any inputs for that?

Comment: Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Accounts") does classpath scanning and will not work in an OSGi environment.

Comment: Gemini JPA uses the Extender Pattern to locate your persistence.xml file. Therefore the JPA extender will wait for bundles that contain a Meta-Persistence header in the manifest. If it finds one it will use this bundles context to find the persistence.xml file within this bundle. The persistence.xml file is then read by Gemini JPA and the entities are loaded using the persistence bunlde context. Then a configured EntityManagerFactory is added as a service into the context. If this doesn't work then maybe your persistence bundle or the JPA extender is not started, Meta-Persistence is missing...

Comment: I checked that MANIFEST.MF is only created when the project is build. But its not present when maven clean is executed. Is it that pom.xml is generating the MANIFEST? If it is how can I update it such that it includes the META-persistence? I tried the code by ensuring all dependencies are up but EMF is not created. Services are not returned. Now how can I update the build so that the manifest include meta-persistence. Kindly help. Thank you